# Getting the ID of an input during an onclick() call?

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple form set up like the following:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="first_number" id="first_number" />
</form>
```

I want to add a button to the form that has an onclick() that gets the value of the text in the input field and sends it to my javascript function called simple_math() that has the parameter "number". For instance:

```
<input type="button" onclick="simple_math(document.getElementById('first_number').value)" />
```

But I know that's the incorrect syntax. Is this possible? Thank you very much!

Comment: That looks correct to me.  Is it not working?

Comment: What does `simple_math()` do? What is not working?

Comment: This should work. Add `alert(first_parameter_name);` (replace with the variable representing the first parameter of the function) at the beginning of your `simple_math` function and you'll see it receives the value correctly. There's probably some error in your function later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but if you are using the value in a math equation, you may need to use parseInt to convert the value from a string to an integer.

Like so:

```
<input type="button" onclick="simple_math( parseInt(document.getElementById('first_number').value, 10) )" />
```

Comment: You might also consider passing a `10` in the second parameter of `parseInt` to tell it you are using base 10 numbers. Otherwise, I've seen it default to octal or some other weird base and parse it in ways you weren't expecting.

Answer (score -1):

Greetings Steve Smelty 
can i propuse to u to add the firebug plugin to your firefox browser it will tell you the error , and if you have an error appears tell it to us please to help you

Comment: Why would you assume he has FireFox installed?

Comment: i am trying to help to make him know how to find out where is the error :) any way thanks for the -1 you r so kind :)